# the variation of the measure under a quasisymmeric homeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory

Let f be a quasisymmetric homeomorphism from the unit circle S^{1} to S^{1}. Let A be a subset of S^{1} whose 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure is zero. My question is : 
 Does f(A) also have 1-dimensional measure zero? If it does, how to prove it?

Comment: What does "quasisymmetric" mean?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Ahlfors and Beurling, in the paper where they introduced quasisymmetric functions give an example of such function which is not absolutely continuous.
Acta math. 96 (1956) 125-142.